# How work with SAFEARRAY ** in Qt ActiveX

Tags: qt, activex, safearray

How work with `SAFEARRAY **` in Qt ActiveX? What kind of type `SAFEARRAY **` in Qt?

Comment: Your question is rather broad. What exactly is not clear?

Comment: @demonplus The question is not broad at all.

Comment: How Qt transform `SAFEARRAY **` to Qt type? Something as QList<?>* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxbase.html), `SAFEARRAY` is represented as follows:

- `SAFEARRAY(VARIANT)` -> `QList<QVariant>`
- `SAFEARRAY(int), SAFEARRAY(double), SAFEARRAY(Date)` -> `QList<QVariant>`
- `SAFEARRAY(BYTE)` -> `QByteArray`
- `SAFEARRAY(BSTR)` -> `QStringList`

Comment: But documentation by AxObject was return next: **QList***. What next? What is the **QList*** without type? In project mfc some like **SAFEARRAY(EdmViewsInfo)***.

Comment: @BogdanShamborskiy Given that you access the values using the `property` interface, you already get the proper `QList<QVariant>`. You never directly deal with `SAFEARRAY` type. Qt hides it from you.

Comment: I have a problem that the property returns `QList*`, not a `QList<QVariant>`. Maybe something I do not understand?

Comment: @BogdanShamborskiy What "property" returns a pointer?? `QObject::property` (`QAxBase` is-a `QObject`), the one you're supposed to be using, returns values, not pointers to values. If you're talking of another method, let us know which one.